# Spotify: Find playlists by songs in the playlist

Tags: spotify

Let's say I want to find all user playlists that include the track 'Roygbiv' by Boards of Canada. Is it possible to modify the function below to make this happen?

```
    var mySearch = Search.search('Roygbiv');
    mySearch.playlists.snapshot().done(function(p){
        searchPlaylists.innerHTML = '<h4>Playlists (' + p.length + ')</h4>';
        var playlistsResults = [];
        for (var i = 0, l = Math.min(p.range.length, maxResults); i < l; i++) {
            playlistsResults.push('<a href="' + p.get(i).uri + '">' + p.get(i).name + '</a>');
        }
        searchPlaylists.innerHTML += '<p>' + playlistsResults.join(', ') + '...</p>';
    });
```